# Allow Data Push into an Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, etl

I'm relatively new to Azure and am having trouble finding what options are out there for connecting to an existing SQL database to push data into it.

The situation is that we have an external client who needs to connect to our Azure SQL database to push data into it, on an on-going basis.  We can't give them permission to get into our database, so we're looking at what we can do allow data in.  At this point the best option seems to be to create a web service deployed in Azure that will validate the data and then push it into our database.

The question I have is, are there other options to do this in an easier way?  Are there Azure services or processes that can be set up to automatically process a file and pull the data into a database?  Any other go-between options when each side has their own database and for security reasons can't just open up access to it?

Comment: They can run an ssis package,provided you have some logic to validate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/?cdn=disable) works great for basic ETL. If neither party can grant direct access, you can use an intermediate repository like [Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/) to drop csv/xml/json files for ingestion. If they'll grant you access to pull, you can setup a linked service that more or less functions the same as a linked server in MSSQL. As of the last release ADF now supports [Azure hosted SSIS packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure) too.

Comment: The answer probably is somewhat similar to this. You don't trust them to allow them to touch your db, they don't trust you to let you get too close to their db. Sort of a hostage situation. Find a common place where both of you feel safe, and put the data there. When the other has left the data, you pick it from there, count the money, i mean, check it's valid, and import it into your database. SSIS or data factory on both sides can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this via [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017) using SQL Studio Managemenet Studio (if it's a one time operation). If you plan to do this repeatedly, you could schedule the SSIS job to execute on schedule. SSIS will do bulk inserts using small batches so you shouldn't have transaction log issues and it should be efficient (because of bulk inserting). Before you do this insert though, you will probably want to consider your performance tier so you don't get major throttling by Azure and possible timeouts.